# What are some database persistence design patterns?

Tags: c++, database, design-patterns, persistence

Are there any standard design patterns for C++ database object persistence?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'll have a look for how to do it now.

Comment: Yup!  Just check the little check mark button next to the answer you want to accept.  That person will get 15 rep points, and you'll get 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Design Patterns for Data Persistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx) - The code samples are C#, but the concepts still apply.